# Spring JPA не создает таблицы

Tags: postgresql, spring, kotlin, jpa

Я работаю с Spring JPA, PostgreSQL и Kotlin

У меня есть следующая сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_branch")
class Branch {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_branch")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var idBranch: Int? = null

    @Column(name = "name_branch")
    var nameBranch: String? = null

    constructor(nameBranch: String){
        this.nameBranch = nameBranch
    }
}
```

Такой файл конфигурации:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
    username: root
    password: "1234"
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
        naming:
          implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
          physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        show_sql: true
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    database: postgresql

jwt:
  sessionTime: 120000000
  secret: secret_key
```

Когда я пытаюсь добавлять новые данные в эту таблицу, получаю сообщение:

```
ERROR 18441 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "table_branch" does not exist
```

Spring не создает таблицу? Что я делаю не так?

Причем, у меня есть другая сущность, для которой таблица в бд создалась

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, насколько это решение правильно, но оно помогло решить проблему.
В файл конфигурации нужно добавить следующее (дополнительно к тому, что указано в самом вопросе. Формат yml):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
```